# Cosmos DB REPLACE strings in nested Object

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I'm using the Cosmos [Data migration tool to migrate data between environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/import-data#advanced-configuration). During my migration, I need to update the hostname of the website in the data. I was able to do this pretty easily with a query like this with the top level object data:

```
SELECT Farms["name"], Farms["farmerInfo"], REPLACE(Farms["websiteLink"], "thiswebsite", "newHostName") AS websiteLink FROM Farms
```

My Cosmos DB data is structured like (data is just for the example):

```
{  
    "name": "Red's Farm",
    "websiteLink": "www.thiswebsite.com/goats/",
    "farmerInfo": {  
        "name":       "Bob",   
        "websiteLink":      "www.thiswebsite.com/goats/",   
        "hasGoats":    true,  
        "numGoats":    17

    }  
}
```

I don't actually need to modify any of the top level data. The data I need to modify is within the "farmerInfo" object. I've tried a few things but I've had no luck. How can I replace a string in this object using the SQL api?

I want the data to look like this after the migration:

```
{  
        "name": "Red's Farm",
        "websiteLink": "www.thiswebsite.com/goats/",
        "farmerInfo": {  
            "name":       "Bob",   
            "websiteLink":      "www.newHostName.com/goats/",  <--- Updated data
            "hasGoats":    true,   
            "numGoats":    17
 
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `SELECT` statement in your `SELECT` statement to build up the sub objects. As example:

```sql
SELECT 
    c.name,
    c.websiteLink,
    (
        SELECT 
            c.farmerInfo.name, 
            REPLACE(c.farmerInfo.websiteLink, "thiswebsite", "newHostName") AS websiteLink
    ) AS farmerInfo
FROM c
```

Comment: thanks for your help!

I implemented what you suggested using the Select statement. I have one issue after importing.

New query:
SELECT Farms["name"], REPLACE(Farms["websiteLink"], "thiswebsite", "newHostName") AS websiteLink, (SELECT Farms["farmerInfo"], REPLACE(Farms["farmerInfo"]["websiteLink"], "thiswebsite", "newHostName") AS websiteLink) AS farmerInfo FROM Farms

Comment: My model looks like this after import:

"farmerInfo": {  
            "websiteLink":      "www.newHostName.com/goats/",  <--- Updated data

// Original data is within the new data object
"farmerInfo": {  
            "name":       "Bob",   
            "websiteLink":      "www.thiswebsite.com/goats/",  
            "hasGoats":    true,   
            "numGoats":    17
 
        } 
 
        }

Comment: @Tabrock In the example I only wrote two properties to keep it short, but if you want to copy all of the contents of the `farmerInfo` property you need to define each one in the sub `SELECT` statement. So `Farms["farmerInfo"]["hasGoats"]` and `Farms["farmerInfo"]["numGoats"]` as well.

Comment: Thank you @404 for following up. Your guidance helped a ton!

In the end, My query ended up looking like and this resolved the nested data.
**SELECT 
    c.name,
    c.websiteLink,
    (
        SELECT 
            REPLACE(c.farmerInfo.websiteLink, "thiswebsite", "newHostName") AS websiteLink
    ) AS farmerInfo
FROM c**